# Why is this local martingale a martingale?

Tags: martingales, stochastic-integrals, local-martingales, wiener-measure

Let $a(t, \omega)$ be a product measurable ($t$ refering to time and $\omega$ to an elementary event of some probability space) and adapted (to some filtration satisfying the "usual" conditions) process on some finite time interval $[0,T]$.
Further, assume that 
$$\mathbb{E}(\int_0^T a^2(s, \omega) \mathrm{d}s) < \infty$$ 
Then the process $$x(t, \omega):=\int_0^t a(s,\omega)\mathrm{d}W_s(\omega),$$
wherein $W$ denotes a Wiener process, is a square integrable martingale with continuous trajectories (P a.s.). So far the setup.
Now my question:
Why is the following process
$$y(t,\omega)=\int_0^t x(s,\omega)a(s,\omega)\mathrm{d}W_s(\omega)$$
a martingale?
(I can see that the process is a local martingale - but i fail to establish that it is a martingale). I would appreciate some advice/help!

Comment: all local martingales that are integrable are true martingales.  You want to show that the last integral is integrable. How is this last integral composed ?  Do you think of anything that would give you information about the integrability of a product if you have information on the integrability of the factors ?

Comment: @WNG: It is **not** the case that every integrable local martingale is a martingale. The first example illustrating this was found by Johnson & Helms in 1963: Let $B_t$ be three-dimensional Brownian motion. Then $X_t:=1/|B_t|$ is a positive local martingale with $\Bbb E[X_t]<1$ for all $t>0$. It follows that $X_t$ is not a martingale.

Comment: You're right, I even knew that counterexample. In this kind of situation, should I remove my original comment, or leave it to keep a sense in yours?